# Order of events within Overrides Sub (ASP.NET, VB)

Tags: asp.net

Ok, so I have inherited this code and it is doing my head in. It's supposed to redirect unauthenticated OR session timed out requests to the login page. It works fine in Test environment but not in production where the only difference is load balanced servers.
It appears that the Subs are called in a different order on the Production servers, does any one know the sequence these subs should be called in?

```
Private Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    If Request.IsAuthenticated = False Then
    Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx?Requested=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.Url.ToString()))
    End If
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnInit(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnInit(e)
    If Context.Session IsNot Nothing Then
        If Session.IsNewSession Then
            Dim szCookieHeader As String = Request.Headers("Cookie")
            If szCookieHeader IsNot Nothing AndAlso szCookieHeader.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0 Then
                Session.Abandon()
                FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage()
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255758/page-init-vs-oninit

Comment: Thanks Tim, but that doesn't answer the question. The question is not which one to use but what happens when someone uses both? When is the handler called for an overridden event?

Comment: If it would answer your question, it would have been an answer not a comment ;)

Comment: Sorry Tim, getting frustrated. Want to replace code with this soln http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654005/how-to-redirect-to-login-page-when-session-is-expired-asp-net-3-5-formsauthen but need to justify change to management :(