# Benefits of Implemention of both overridden OnInit() & Page_Init event handler?

Tags: asp.net

I do have a small doubt regarding ASP.NET Page Life Cycle events. When gone through the coding of an application I came to see both overriding of OnInit() method and also Page_Init event. I thought both the approaches serves the same purpose and i saw mostly the implementation of overridden OnInt() only but not both. Most of the articles in the web explains about the better approach in these two and I know that generally overriding the OnLoad/OnInit methods is faster and also if you override OnInit and fail to call base.OnInit then the Init event won't be fired but no one explained what happens if we implement both. What does this situation means. Can anyone please help me regarding this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I would recommend you use `Page_Init` or `Page_Load` respectively.

Comment: Hi @rhughes thanks for your recommendation but I would like to know that is there benefit lies behind the above kind of approach that's it.

Comment: Have a look at this question, also on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255758/page-init-vs-oninit

Answer (score 0):

Page_Init is just a shortcut for calling the OnInit override they both do the same thing.  Page_Init requires the AutoEventWireup property to be set to true because it tells the compiler to look at your code for certain methods like Page_Init or Page_Load and fire them, this video from Fritz Onion on pluralsight does a really good job of explaining it:  [ASP.Net 3.5 Pluralsight Course](http://pluralsight.com/training/Player?author=fritz-onion&name=aspdotnet-architecture&mode=live&clip=11&course=aspdotnet-fundamentals)